# If $11^m\cdot 5^n-3^p\cdot 2^q=1$ where $m,n,p,q$ are non-negative integers,Find all $m,n,p,q$

Tags: number-theory

If $11^m\cdot 5^n-3^p\cdot 2^q=1$ where $m,n,p,q$ are non-negative integers, Find all $m,n,p,q$.

It seems $(1,1,3,1),(0,1,0,2),(0,2,1,3)$ are the only solutions.

Now, the idea is to plug $m=1+x,n=1+y,p=3+z,q=1+r$ with $x,y,z,r \ge 1$

It gives me $55(11^x\cdot 5^y)-54(3^z\cdot 2^r)=1$..How to proceed from here?

Comment: No there are more solutions like (0,1,0,2) and (0,2,1,3)

Comment: I'm guessing the exponents were meant to be strictly positive.  Can the OP please edit accordingly?

Comment: By Mihăilescu's theorem we know that there are no solutions of the form $(0,n,p,0)$, $(m,0,p,0)$ or $(m,0,0,q)$ and only one solution of the form $(0,n,0,q)$, namely $(0,1,0,2)$.

Comment: how will you argue for $(1,1,3,1)$?

Comment: Lorraine Foster and/or Leo Alex wrote a series of papers on equations like the one you are studying. I recommend having a look through the literature for their papers.

Comment: I would be obliged if you give me the link @Gerry Myerson

Comment: I don't have one. If you have access to Math Reviews online (a univeristy library probably will), you can just search it for papers by those people. If not, you can type their names into Google, maybe with some keyphrase like "diophantine equations", to see what comes up. Anyway, I have told you what to look for – if you're really interested in the question, you'll find a way to get at the papers.

Comment: I hope you are talking about exponential diophantine equations

Comment: checking modulo 5 and modulo 3 may help

Comment: You can do this working modulo $2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 11$ and invoking Mihailescu (or some weaker version).

Answer (score 0):

A PARTIAL ANSWER.-Seeking positive solutions $mnpq\ne 0$ (or its impossibility) we prove that if $n>1$ then there are no solutions. Besides we give restrictions on the exponents $m,p,q$
►Consider the equation $$11x-3y=1\qquad(*)$$
A solution of $(*)$ is $(x,y)=(5,18)$ so the general solutions is given by
$$(x,y)=(3t+5,11t+18)$$ It follows the equations
$$\begin{cases}3t+5=11^{m-1}5^n\\11t+18=3^{p-1}2^q\end{cases}\qquad(**)$$
It is seen in $(**)$ that $t$ must be multiple of $5$ (first equation)and of $2$ (second equation) hence $t=10s$ so one has 
$$30s+5=11^{m-1}5^n$$
If $n>1$ then $1\equiv 5\pmod {10}$ thus since we are looking for $n$ positive, $\color{red}{n=1}$.
 Furthermore, if $p>1$ we get $t=30s$ so one has 
$$\begin{cases}900s+5=11^{m-1}5^n\\330s+18=3^{p-1}2^q\end{cases}\qquad(***)$$ and the second equation in $(***)$ gives $8\equiv3^{p-1}2^q\pmod {10}$ so 
$$(p-1,q)\in \{(1,4),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3)\}\text{modulo}\space 4$$
The proposed equation becomes in the following 
four possibilities to study
$$\begin{cases}5\cdot11^m-3^{2+4r}2^{4s}=1\\5\cdot11^m-3^{3+4r}2^{1+4s}=1\\5\cdot11^m-3^{4r}2^{2+4s}=1\\5\cdot11^m-3^{1+4r}2^{3+4s}=1\end{cases}$$